# Lagrange's equations derivations

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

While deriving lagrange's equation, for an infinitesimal displacement $\vec{dr}$, we express it using taylor series in terms of general coordinates as $\frac{\vec{dr}}{dq} \delta q$. Where $\frac{\vec{dr}}{dq}$ means derivative of $\vec{r}$.  What does it mean?(this derivative term). What is the function whose derivative we are taking ?

Comment: The $q$ is a single (generalized) coordinate on which the position vector $\vec{r}$ may depend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classical point mechanics with [constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_%28mathematics%29) we usually assume that the $i$th position vector

$${\bf r}_i~=~{\bf r}_i (q^1, \ldots, q^n;t) $$

of the $i$th point particle is a function of $n$ [generalized coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $q^1$, $\ldots$, $q^n$, and time $t$. For fixed $t$, the generalized coordinates $q^j$ parametrize the [virtual displacements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement), i.e. the displacements that obey the constraints. For further details, see e.g. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Chap. 1.